# play background music in a loop Qt

Tags: qt, qmediaplayer

I want to play background music continually in a loop until the game ends.

in the header file:

```
    QMediaPlayer * music = new QMediaPlayer();
```

in the cpp file:

```
    startGame(){
    music->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/backgroundmusic.mp3"));
    music->play();  }

   stopGame(){
   music->stop(); }
```

Right now my music plays thru to the end but does not restart. How can I get it to loop over again again?
Is there a QMediaPlayer member I can use, or should I run it in a while loop, or what?

Comment: Use QMediaPlaylist for that as said in the answer of p4plus2. Or try working around with the `mediaStatusChanged` signal. You could connect it to a slot that checks for status `QMediaPlayer::EndOfMedia` and then starts playback again. ... But prefer QMediaPlaylist. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is `QMediaPlaylist`.  `QMediaPlaylist` allows you to control the playback mode, and in this case you would use `Loop`. This approach has other advantages too, such as `CurrentItemInLoop`.  `CurrentItemInLoop` will play the current playlist item in a loop, meaning that if you add more songs in the future you can select a song then loop only that track.  Thus, you only need a single playlist for most needs.  Below is some example code, I do not currently have a means to test it though (No Qt multimedia extensions installed on this machine).  Should demonstrate the point reasonably well though.

```
QMediaPlaylist *playlist = new QMediaPlaylist();
playlist->addMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/backgroundmusic.mp3"));
playlist->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::Loop);

QMediaPlayer *music = new QMediaPlayer();
music->setPlaylist(playlist);
music->play();
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to get this to loop without a pause in the middle?