# I want to play only one mp3 file in loop Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

I have only one mp3 file paying in background. I want that mp3 file to played till I close the application.
What I am facing is that the mp3 file is played for only once and then stops. I want it to be played again.
Find sample code below

Code:

```
QMediaPlayer *music = new QMediaPlayer();
music->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/bgsound.mp3"));
music->setVolume(20);
music->play();
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you checked `QMediaPlayer`'s API for anyhing useful for that?

Comment: See the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690616/play-background-music-in-a-loop-qt). It's a bit bigger example, containing the method `QMediaPlaylist::setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::Loop)`, which you might be interested in as well.

Comment: I tried this earlier but it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do it by connecting signals and slots as follows:

```
connect(music,&QMediaPlayer::mediaStatusChanged,music,&QMediaPlayer::play);
```

Comment: You're welcome :). Please select the check mark on the left side of your question to accept the solution and let the others know the right answer. Thanks @PreetamShetty

Comment: Sorry, the check mark is located on the left side of my answer :))